# jQuery: Scroll to bottom on element not working after certain overflow height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm attempting to code a live chat based off jQuery and PHP, where (when the user sends a message) their chat is automatically scrolled to the bottom to show the latest message.

When a message is sent or received, I use jQuery's append function to add a new div to the containing element, which contains every chat message in a separate div.

Initially, this works. When I send a message, the chat is scrolled to the bottom of the element (otherwise it would need to be scrolled down manually). After quite a few messages, however, it begins scrolling to the middle/upper section of the chat, rather than the bottom.

This is the jQuery that scrolls the chat down:

```
$('.live--chat--box--body').scrollTop($('.live--chat--box--body')[0].scrollHeight);
```

This is the HTML code of the element containing the chat:

```
<div class="live--chat--box--body">
    <div class="live--chat--top"></div>
    <div class="chat--message--container chat--message--container--self">
        <div class="chat--message chat--message--self">
            <span> Message 1 </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The third-nested div, *chat--message--container*, is repeated for each message sent.

This is the CSS for the *live--chat--box--body* element:

```
float: left;
width: 100%;
max-height: 245px;
height: 245px;
padding: 7px;
box-sizing: border-box;
background-color: #fafafa;
border: 1px solid #d7d7d7;
border-top: none;
border-radius: 1px 1px 0 0;
overflow-y: auto;
position: relative;
```

My theory is that, once the chat reaches a certain height, it begins to use the maximum height in the CSS rather than the actual height of the element, meaning it would only take you to the bottom of the maximum height - rather than the whole height. Though, this happens AFTER the user is allowed to scroll, suggesting that it's already exceeded the maximum height allowed before overflowing.

If anybody knows why this is happening, I'm fascinated to know.

Comment: A jsfiddle makes it easier to understand...

Comment: Completely forgot, sorry.

http://jsfiddle.net/Reestv/drb49a0p/2/


Weirdly.. it seems to work fine on there - but on my site it doesn't?

Comment: @Rees have you got the solution ? i'm facing same problem right now.